# Change view of fragment or change fragment?

Tags: android, view, fragment, profile

What is the best practice here?

Doing a profile page, clicking on edit button brings up edittext instead of text view.

Option 1) Clicking edit button changes entire view of fragment A

Option 2) Clicking edit button brings up another fragment B

Answer (score 0):

I would say clicking the edit button takes you to another fragment. this would be a best practice.

you can do something like this

```
btnid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = new tasks(); 
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); 
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
} 
});
```

you will need to replace the btnid with the ID of the button, and the R.id.content_frame with the fragment one